# System verilog assertion - $rose

Tags: system-verilog, formal-verification, system-verilog-assertions

[image]I want to write an assertion where it says the req should go high 4 cycles after next posedge of done. For me at reset the done is already high. How can I make request go high at next posedge of done.`assert property {$rose(done) |-> ##4 req}` But I dont know why it is not working. Can anybody please help?

Comment: What does "it's not working" exactly mean?

Answer (score 1):

If done starts out high and you want to wait for it to fall and then rise again, try:

```
assert property (!done ##1 $rose(done) |-> ##4 req)
```

But that just assures req will be high four cycles after the rising edge of done.  It says nothing of when that happens (could have been two cycles ago, could have been before done even asserted).  If you want to strictly enforce req rising four cycles after done, try this instead:

```
assert property (!done ##1 $rose(done) |-> ##4 $rose(req))
```

Comment: Thanks T.J but Either of solution not working. I cannot control done signal I can only give reference of that signal (I cannot make done go low). I added a picture to the question for clarification. Basically it should go high after next rising edge.

Comment: @TJ `!done ##1 $rose(done)` is equivalent to `$rose(done)` in terms of when they match. (baring any unknown values for done, i.e. X or Z). It's just the start time that's different.

Comment: @TJ If you want to enforce that `req` goes high exactly 4 cycles after done, you have to say: `$rose(done) |-> !req [*4] ##1 req`

Comment: @Tudor I found with simulators (and some FV tools) $rose by itself matches the first cycle spuriously because done changes from unknown to 1.  Also, I allowed for req to fall and then rise again after done asserts, so your code is the more strict.

Comment: @eshankanoje I just tried it on a test design, and it seems to work.  I'll update my answer with a witness waveform, once I get that part working (new FV tool, getting help from the AE).

Comment: @T.J. True and the OP did say he wants to filter out the initial `done` when coming out of reset.

Comment: @eshankanoje Maybe you want to focus yourself on the situation that caused `done` to go low and use that as a trigger condition: `done_goes_low_because whatever ##[*] $rose(done) ...`.

Comment: @Tudor Thats what my problem is, I cannot control done signal. The tool randomizes transition of done signal.  I can only give reference of that signal.

Comment: @eshankanoje Right, the FV tool will play the role of an overzealous verification engineer and try to break your design in any way possible, including having done start low unless that violates protocol (which you specify using `assume property`).  So you could try `assume property($fell(reset) |-> done)` to keep done high on reset.  Keep in mind any assumptions (constraints) you set have to be verified at the next level, though, or you may just be masking a potential bug.

Comment: @T.J Exactly. I am using active low reset so cannot use above assumption either. I come up with something like this. ` 1. $rose(done) |-> ##4 req 2. $fell(done) |=> !req 3. !done |-> !req`. But still facing issues. Can you please suggest something